# Exceptions Handler with HipHop Virtual Machine

Tags: hhvm

Any one knows hhvm's runtime option to use a custom exception handler. The official documentation mentions these values:

```
ErrorHandling {
 CallUserHandlerOnFatals = true
 NoInfiniteLoopDetection = false
 NoInfiniteRecursionDetection = false
 MaxStackDepth = 1000
 ThrowBadTypeExceptions = false
 ThrowNotices = false
 NoticeFrequency = 1    # 1 out of these many notices to log
 WarningFrequency = 1   # 1 out of these many warnings to log
 AssertActive = false
 AssertWarning = false
}
```

But it doesn't provide definitions or any other option to handle exceptions from php. Actually, when I start hhvm with those options present it wanrs that some of those options nodes are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

For CallUserHandlerOnFatals to work, I believe you need to register a custom error handling using PHP's set_error_handler() function.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php